# What is the equivalent to C++ pointers on Kotlin?

Tags: c++, kotlin

I have a method which swaps the value of two variables.

```
void switchValue(int* a , int* b){
      //logic here...
}
```

C++ works on a lower level than Kotlin but can I do this on Kotlin?

Comment: what does it mean to "switch the values of two variables" ? To you mean swap?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for pass by reference?

Comment: Note: Swap Function in Kotlin question has no valid answers at all...

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638871/pass-an-integer-by-reference-in-kotlin) for further info on passing by reference in kotlin (TL;DR it's a hack, try and stay away from that kind of things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to do this with a function in Kotlin or Java, because references can only be passed by value. (Unless you're satisfied with using a wrapper class and you swap what two wrapper instances are referencing, but this would be clumsy.)

This is probably the easiest way to swap two variables' values:

```
var x = 0
var y = 1

//swap:
x = y.also { y = x }
```

**Edit:** A bit of correction. You can sort of do it with properties using reflection. This wouldn't work on local variables, though.

```
fun <T> swap(first: KMutableProperty0<T>, second: KMutableProperty0<T>) {
    first.set(second.get().also { second.set(first.get()) })
}

swap(::x, ::y)
```

In my opinion, this kind of practice (remotely changing variable values), although common in C/C++, should be avoided.

Comment: I'm no Kotlin expert, but this looks like it should work - not sure why the downvote