# In Kotlin, if an object is passed into a new instance of a class and then some properties are changed, will it change in the original object?

Tags: kotlin

The question is in the title: 
In Kotlin, if an object is passed into a new instance of a class and then some properties are changed, will it change the properties in the original object?
Image I've got the following situation:

```
class User{
   var name: String = "initial name"
}
class UserHolder{
   companion object{
      var INSTANCE: User
   }
}
class ClassA{
   fun doStuff(){
       val classB = ClassB(UserHolder.INSTANCE)
       classB.changeUser()
       val newName = UserHolder.INSTANCE.name // is it "initial name" or "My new name"?
   }
}
class ClassB(private val user: User){
   fun changeUser(){
       user.name = "My new name"
    }
}
```

will the newName be is "initial name" or "My new name" and why?
I know that if I pass an object into a method and change its properties, then on return the properties will be updated. But why doesn't it work with the classes? Is it because we write 'val user'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the answers in [Is Kotlin "pass-by-value" or "pass-by-reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515031/is-kotlin-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference) when you pass an object to a function you pass a copy of the reference. Through this reference you are able to modify the passed object.

The reason you cannot modify `Instance.name` is because you declared `User.name` as `val`. [`val`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) is for read-only properties that can not change and therefore can not be reassigned.

If you change it to `var` you can modify it. See https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/7t8j73oqdtiin3ja8atbdq15op/lhiik2ek7otonb3kklpk33jclg

```
class User{
   var name: String = "initial name"
}
class UserHolder{
   companion object{
      var INSTANCE : User = User()
   }
}
class ClassA{
   fun doStuff(){
       val classB = ClassB(UserHolder.INSTANCE)
       classB.changeUser()
       val newName = UserHolder.INSTANCE.name // is it "initial name" or "My new name"?
   }
}
class ClassB(private val user: User){
   fun changeUser(){
       user.name = "My new name"
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>){
    System.out.println(UserHolder.INSTANCE.name)
    val classA = ClassA()
    classA.doStuff()
    System.out.println(UserHolder.INSTANCE.name)
}
```

prints:

```
initial name
My new name
```

Comment: Oh yes, that was my bad. I asked my server for a user and updated INSTANCE before checking if the name's changed. Now it makes sense. P.S. I changed val to var (it should have been var from the beginning, it was a typo)