# Does Kotlin allow for `optionally` passing by reference like the & in php?

Tags: php, kotlin, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

In PHP you can optionally make parameters pass by reference with an `&` in the function definition:

```
someFunction($byValue, &$byReference) {
    // $byValue is passed in by value
    // $byReference is passed in by reference due to the preceding &
}
```

Is this possible in Kotlin?  If not, does anyone know if it's planned?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689951/1246282

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Kotlin "pass-by-value" or "pass-by-reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515031/is-kotlin-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

Comment: @Quinn yes the answer to my question can be derived from the question you linked though I don't see it as a direct duplicate as stated in the comment on your own answer.

Comment: @wheelmaker Yes you're right, it is not a direct duplicate, just a similar question. Sorry for my phrasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that similar to Java, Kotlin is always pass-by-value and optional pass-by-reference is not possible.

Comment: Do you believe that or do you have any sources or even some code providing an example about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase see the duplicate question i linked in the comments