# How to pass a variable from main function to another function and modify it? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I am aware that an argument passed to a function will be seen as "val", even if the variable was initialized as "var". But this has been a problem for me. In this example code below, I want to modify the value of variable "num" by using the function "changeNum". But of course, Kotlin won't allow me to modify it. How do I get around this? How can I use the function "changeNum" to modify the variable "num"?

```
fun main() {
    var num: Int = 5
    changeNum(num)
}

fun changeNum(num: Int){
    num += 2
    print(num)
}
```

Comment: so why dont you change your method changeNum to `fun changeNum(num: Int): Int` then return value you want?

Comment: agreed with @Steve.P. Also check that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689951/5153846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin is pass-by-value, so you can't do that directly with primitive types like `Int`.

The usual approach is to just return a new value instead of modifying what you receive as argument (a functional approach). It makes it clearer from the calling code's perspective:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var num: Int = 5
    num = changeNum(num)
}

fun changeNum(num: Int): Int {
    val newValue = num + 2
    print(newValue)
    return newValue
}
```

If you really want to mutate the variable instead of returning a new value, here are 2 approaches I'm thinking of to do this:

1. put all the code operating on this value into a class, and make the local variable a property of that class (this is the OO approach)
2. put this primitive variable into a class, and pass an instance of that class

Option 1 would look like this:

```kotlin
class SomeClass(var num: Int) {

    fun changeNum() {
        num += 2
        print(num)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val container = SomeClass(5)
    container.changeNum()
}
```

Option 2 would look like this:

```kotlin
class SomeMutableContainer(var num: Int)

fun main() {
    val container = SomeMutableContainer(5)
    changeNum(container)
}

fun changeNum(container: SomeMutableContainer) {
    container.num += 2
    print(container.num)
}
```

Comment: You could do it by passing the property: `fun changeNum(num: MutableProperty<Int>) {}`

Comment: I guess `MutableProperty` is a special case of the `SomeMutableContainer` option - a built-in one. Although I don't believe it would be desirable to use properties in this manner for regular business code (maybe for framework code it could be ok, though)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this in Kotlin with a **property**

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty0

var num = 1

fun main() {
    println(num)
    changeNum(::num)
    println(num)
}

fun changeNum(numProperty: KMutableProperty0<Int>) {
    numProperty.set(12345)
}

>> 1
>> 12345
```

A [`KMutableProperty0`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-mutable-property0/) represents a basic `var`, so you can pass in a property reference using the `::num` syntax (same as how you'd pass a function reference). That way, instead of passing the current value, you're providing the function with a reference to the property itself, and then you can call `set` on it.

But the question is, do you really want to do this? Or are you overcomplicating something that should be done in a more simple way, or a more readable one? You can't actually do this with a **variable**, like you're trying to do inside `fun main()`, only **properties** on an object (top-level vars, basically) - but even if you could, why wouldn't you just do this instead?

```
fun main() {
    var num: Int = 5
    ...
    num = changeNum(num) // this would need renaming but y'know
}
```

it's still a one-line call, your `changeNum` function can still have side effects, do validation etc, it just returns the result instead of setting it as a side effect. This is a lot easier to follow, especially when it's the usual way of setting a value on a thing.

---

If you really want to use references, but making them top-level in your class is messy, then maybe consider creating a state object instead:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty0

data class AllThemNums(var num1 :Int = 1, var num2: Int = 9999)

fun main() {
    val nums = AllThemNums(num1 = 5)
    changeNum(nums::num1)
    println(nums)
}

fun changeNum(numProperty: KMutableProperty0<Int>) {
    numProperty.set(numProperty.get() + 2)
}


>> AllThemNums(num1=7, num2=9999)
```

you could even put the `changeNum` function inside the data class!

Answer (score 0):

Im my project, I've defined a generic type for enclosing all scalar types, both primitives and user-defined.

```
     data class pTp<T>(var v: T)
```

So I can create

```
    fun PercAcumNorm(percAcum:pTp<Double>, perc:pTp<Double>, 
              valor:Double, Soma:Double)
    { 
      perc.v = valor/soma
      parcAcum.v += perc.v
    }
```

Then one just needs to call

```
   ....
   var pAcum:pTp<Double> = pTp(0.40)
   var p = 0
   var valor = 5
   var soma = 100      
   percCalc(pAcum, p, soma, valor)
   println(pAcum.v)  // it prints 0.45
```

It's not the cleanest solution, but it's what can be done without using Kotlin's built-in features, which may be modified in the future.