# apply function does not work for basic types in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to use apply function for assign a new value to a variable.
when i try apply() to re-assign a value to a parameter of a data class it works correctly. but when i have not a data class it does not work!

data class example:

```
    data class A(
        var a: Int,
    )

    val a1 = A(3)
    val a2 = a1.apply {
        a = 5
    }
    println("a1 = ${a1.a}, a2 = ${a2.a}")
```

basic type example:

```
    var a1 = 3
    var a2 = a1.apply {
        a1 = 5
    }
    println("a1 = $a1, a2 = $a2")
```

the result of first example is:

```
a1 = 5, a2 = 5
```

but the result of second example is:

```
a1 = 5, a2 = 3
```

I don't understand why `a2` still is 3 and apply does not work for it!
I expected the `a1 = 5` re-assign 5 value to `a2` but it does not!
Can you explain it?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515031/is-kotlin-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're returning 'a1' and reassigning it to 3 in the same statement. I've no idea of what to expect even. in your first example you're changing an existing object and returning the same reference

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for your mention. i did not see that before your comment and when i read it i completely understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Int class is immutable. You cannot change the value of an instance of it. Note the difference in your two code samples. In the first, you are changing the `a` property of your `A` class to have a different value. So, you are *mutating* the instance of `A`.

In your second code sample, you are not changing a value that is inside the instance. You are changing your variable `a1` to point to a completely different instance of Int. Your `apply` block is pointless, because you aren't using it to call any *member* functions or properties of the Int class. You are directly reassigning the variable `a1`.

All the Kotlin standard library Number classes, as well as String, BigInteger, and BigDecimal, are immutable classes, where you cannot change the value inside the instance. You can only reassign variables/properties to point to other instances.